# Using MS Band to generate the path

Tags: c#, google-maps, bing-maps, uwp, microsoft-band

:)

I'm currently working on my project using Microsoft Band 2 connected to UWP app, written in C#. In some portion of this project, the system show a path to follow from user's current point (who is wearing Microsoft Band) to the destination, at the floor plan scale (The system can tell you which floor you need to go).

Problems I'm facing are:

1. How to get the current location from the Band? Or there's another
   possibility or channel to get this information from the Band such as MS Health?
2. Since Google Maps provides floor plan and direction to go (route generator), in what way I can send the retrieved location and get the generated path back from my UWP app?
3. Is the thing I tried to do in 2. can be implemented by using Bing Maps as my map provider?

Anyway, thank you for all suggestions here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually built a prototype to navigation app for the original band. Here is what I found when I came across the same questions:

1. The band doesn't expose it's location through an API. The GPS uses up a lot of battery power. Having a couple of apps using the GPS would drain your battery in a couple of hours which would create a bigger issue for the user. The way around this is to have a companion app that runs on the users mobile device and use it's GPS. This is what I did in my app and it worked well.
2. Bing Maps actually has much more detailed floor plans than Google Maps, called venue maps. You might want to check them out. However I don't think they have been exposed through the UAP app yet.https://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#VenueMapsModule3 Google Maps is likely not an option as I don't believe they expose their floor plan data via a public service. Also, determining which floor the user is on will be very difficult. You can approximate, but you will run into errors here.
3. Mixing Google and Bing map data is against the terms of use of both platforms.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it seems that Venue Maps don't have a floor plans for the building in my country. However, most of my floor plan usage involves with the department stores, which are available in Google Maps. But I will keep your suggestion for my further development :)

Comment: ITs also worth noting that the accuracy of GPS devices in phones are usually only accurate to 15 meters. When in buildings you will be luck if you can get a GPS signal. GPS devices really aren't an option for indoor navigation.

Comment: Do you have documentations or references about the violation about Google and Bing Map mixture in question 3?

Comment: This is in the terms of use of both platforms. I work on the Bing Maps team and also work with a lot of former Google Maps customers as well. I know the terms of use of both platforms very well. Bing maps has this restriction as it is a requirements by its data providers (i.e. HERE). Google Maps likely has the same reason for having this restriction, but tend to be a bit more aggressive when it comes to enforcing it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question #1, the Band SDK does not expose the GPS sensor of the Band.  However, one can use the GPS sensor on the phone on which the application is running.  Since the phone and the Band are in the same location--as I assume the user's holding it in order to see the generated directions--the phone's GPS sensor should be adequate (and will save battery life on the Band anyway).

I'm not very familiar with the Google or Bing Maps APIs, so I can't speak to questions #2 and #3.

Comment: A bit sad about the Band limitation ;(

Answer (score 0):

Although the Band has built-in GPS, it's not possible with the Band SDK to get the location via GPS. It would be better to use the phone's GPS as it locks faster and thus requires less energy. To run your app and have access to your Band, the phone needs to be within reach of the Band anyway, so this should be possible, right?

The other two points: I'd suggest you to go with the Windows MapControl as it also works offline and is integrated into the UWP framework. There's no need to use Google services, if you ask me.

First, you need to display your floor plan with many polygons, I assume. Be sure to use the 10586 SDK as it also allows you to draw holes in polygons - just in case you have such rooms etc.

To get the direction between two points, you can use this code ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt219701.aspx)):

```
BasicGeoposition startLocation = new BasicGeoposition() {Latitude=47.643,Longitude=-122.131};

// End at the city of Seattle, Washington.
BasicGeoposition endLocation = new BasicGeoposition() {Latitude = 47.604,Longitude= -122.329};

// Get the route between the points.
MapRouteFinderResult routeResult =
     await MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync(
     new Geopoint(startLocation),
     new Geopoint(endLocation),
     MapRouteOptimization.Time,
     MapRouteRestrictions.None);

if (routeResult.Status == MapRouteFinderStatus.Success)
{
    DrawPathOnMapControl(routeResult.Route.Legs);
}
```

In the `DrawPathOnMapControl` method you use the given legs to draw polylines on your map.